# Algorithm or a tool to compare two spectrogram outputs for unit testing purposes

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, spectrogram

I am looking for a good algorithm or a tool to compare two spectrogram outputs for unit testing. I can visually confirm the outputs are similar but I would like to automate this process. The basic stats of the outputs, such as min/max/avg/median are kind of the same but this would not catch true differences.

Comment: A spectrogram is just a matrix. Have you considered one of the matrix difference metrics?

Comment: @MBaz what would be good metrics to compare two matrices? Like some kind of norm?

Comment: If this is for subjective audio purposes (?), there are tools that effectively do something similar (pesq, peaq etc)

Comment: Unit testing must be based on the actual specification of the requirements. There is a huge span between "must be bit-exact"  to "sounds more or less the same". Without a better description of your application what you consider a "pass" or "fail"